# I'm trying to compile an interactive diagram example using GLMakie and it's not working. What can I do?

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I just can't run the example available here https://juliadynamics.github.io/InteractiveDynamics.jl/dev/cobweb/

I copied and pasted this code into a file called "example_cobweb.jl" and when I run it doesn't work. I've already tried `]build GLMakie`.

```
using InteractiveDynamics, GLMakie, DynamicalSystems

# the second range is a convenience for intermittency example of logistic
rrange = 1:0.001:4.0
# rrange = (rc = 1 + sqrt(8); [rc, rc - 1e-5, rc - 1e-3])

lo = Systems.logistic(0.4; r=rrange[1])

interactive_cobweb(lo, rrange, 5)
```

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is that you need to install the packages `GLMakie, Makie, CairoMakie.` So if you go into julia and tap the "]" key to open the package manager and type `add GLMakie, Makie, CairoMakie.`.

It looks like from the pictures, that you tried to install `GLMakie` already. Perhaps you can try this.

1. Add the other backends like I said, GLMakie, Makie, and CairoMakie.
2. update your packages using the `update` command from the package manager prompt.
3. In the main Julia project, type `using Pkg; Pkg.precompile()`

That might cover all the bases.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @JoãoVitorVieiraFlauzino hmm, I see that you tried to install GLMakie. So when you go into the package manager prompt and type `status` do you see GLMakie listed as one of the packages?

Comment: Yes, I do. A printscreen: <https://imgur.com/a/vDNF5M6>

Comment: Hmm, seems like you have `GLMakie` installed, but an old version. I think this is probably due to having PlotlyJS package installed as well. PlotlyJS has some dependencies that can prevent GLMakie from upgrading. So there are 2 things to try. 1. Uninstall PlotlyJS with `rm PlotlyJS`, and then run an `update` in the package manager. The other thing to try is to keep PlotlyJS but then type `add WebIO#master` in the package manager. It might be that the dependency issue is causing GLMakie to not load.

Comment: The first option didn't work. So I tried the second option and then updated. Using `]status`, I saw that GLMakie is updated to version 0.4.4. But now this has appeared:

Comment: ```Warning:     GLFW couldn't create an OpenGL window.
│     This likely means, you don't have an OpenGL capable Graphic Card,
│     or you don't have an OpenGL 3.3 capable video driver installed.
│     Have a look at the troubleshooting section in the GLMakie readme:
│     https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/tree/master/GLMakie#troubleshooting-opengl.
└ @ GLMakie ~/.julia/packages/GLMakie/rXGL8/src/screen.jl:336
ERROR: LoadError: GLFWError (API_UNAVAILABLE): GLX: No GLXFBConfigs returned
Stacktrace:
```

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if this is probably reflecting a completely different problem. Maybe try creating a totally new julia environment and loading all the packages there. That way everything is fresh and there is less chance for some lingering dependency.